# Log UserName and IP with Custom Properties in Application Insight .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-2.1

We are running an intranet Application on .Net Core 2.0. Application insight is very helpfull to catch exceptions. So when the User comes up to us for support we would like to find his request that caused problems in application insight. I added an ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer like this:

```
public class CustomTelemetry : ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor ;

        public CustomTelemetry(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements initialization logic.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="platformContext">Http context.</param>
        /// <param name="requestTelemetry">Request telemetry object associated with the current request.</param>
        /// <param name="telemetry">Telemetry item to initialize.</param>
        protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(HttpContext platformContext, RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, ITelemetry telemetry)
        {

            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("UserName", _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Location.Ip))
            {
                LocationContext location = requestTelemetry.Context.Location;
                telemetry.Context.Location.Ip = location.Ip;
                requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("InternalIP", location.Ip);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Initalizer is registered at startup like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetry>();
```

When I look at the requests Custom Data still turns up empty.
[image: Application Insight Custom Data]
Did I register it wrong? I found the exact same line to add the service in the Integration Tests of Application Insights (although commented out...)
Has anyone an Idea whats wrong?

Comment: 2 suggestions: first, try setting a breakpoint and see what is happening. Second: instead of deriving from `ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer` just implement  `ITelemetryProcessor` as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor). What is the added value of deriving from `ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer` anyway?

Comment: Also, I don't know just using the DI mechanism works. According to the docs you must use it using config or code `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers
        .Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());`

Comment: thanks for you reply peter. My reason for using the ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer is that it censors the IP as soon the Location is known (GDPR stuff that is not relevant to intranet applications). With an override of it's initializer it was possible to get the IP before censoring. (found some example for older versions that don't work anymore).
my problem now is that username is null and the ip ind a v6 format for localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working for my purposes.

```
public class CustomTelemetry : ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor ;

        public CustomTelemetry(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implements initialization logic.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="platformContext">Http context.</param>
        /// <param name="requestTelemetry">Request telemetry object associated with the current request.</param>
        /// <param name="telemetry">Telemetry item to initialize.</param>
        protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(HttpContext platformContext, RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name; // Only set when request failed...
            var ip = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
            if (ip != null) telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.TryAdd("InternalIP", ip);
            if(userName != null) requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("UserName", userName);
        }
     }
```

(Note: ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer is part of AppInsights)

Important here is to get everything from the **HttpContext**, checking if it is null and adding custom properties. The built in properties for IP can get overwritten otherwise. [Migrosoft GDPR Blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/applicationinsights-status/2018/02/01/all-octets-of-ip-address-will-be-set-to-zero/)

In the **Startup** add this to ConfigureService

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetry>();
```

Make sure to add the ContextAccessor beforehand so it can be injected:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

In Configure add this at the beginning:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions{ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto});
```

This is very important to optain the **IP Adress** when using **reverse proxy** like **IIS**. Otherwise you will always receive localhost. UseForwardedHeaders() without options just does nothing! (Also you will need a test setup with a remote server)

Getting the **Username** just seems to work when the Request fails (tested with 500 Internal Server Error). Otherwise the HttpContextAccessor doesn't populate the User object. Could be a 2.1 thing, quite annoying maybe someone finds a way to get it for every request.

In the end your information should arrive at ApplicationInsights and look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add application insights to your asp.net core project via menu option in visual studio:
[image]

Second, in your `CustomTelemetry` class, you'd better set a breakpoint to make sure it can be hit when code is running.

Third, in your `CustomTelemetry` class, please do some logic when `UserName` and `InternalIP` is null or empty. If these values are null or empty, they will not be added.

My test code as below:

CustomTelemetry class:

```
public class CustomTelemetry: ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomTelemetry(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;

        if (!requestTelemetry.Context.Properties.ContainsKey("UserName"))
        {
            //if UserName is null or empty, add a default value for it
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                requestTelemetry.Context.Properties.Add("UserName", "NA");
            }
            else
            {
                requestTelemetry.Context.Properties.Add("UserName", _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            }

        }
        if (!requestTelemetry.Context.Properties.ContainsKey("InternalIP"))
        {
            //update
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestTelemetry.Context.Location.Ip))
            {
                requestTelemetry.Context.Properties.Add("InternalIP", requestTelemetry.Context.Location.Ip);                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then register in `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc();
   services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetry>();
   services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Since I don't have your `ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer` class, just write the above test code. If you need more help, please share that class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have a simillar setup and the Code gets hit with a breakpoint if I use a CustomTelemetryInitializer (but not with a ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer).  The problem seems to be in the httpcontext since there is no IP or User stored in most cases. It's very strange with the IP, some times its 127.0.0.1 or ::1. strange mix between ipv4 and ipv6. also there could be issues with kestrel sitting behind iis. I try UseForwardedHeaders and some more debugging on a remote server.

Comment: Yes, if ip and user have value, then the function can be worked. And if this answer resolves the issue(not logged in app insight), please help mark as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help but I am sorry it doesnt solve the issue of how to log the username and ip to app insight or get a ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer up and running.

Comment: @Yush0, for the ip, I can fetch it now, please see my updated code and the screenshot for test result. The only change is:                                                    `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestTelemetry.Context.Location.Ip))
            {
                requestTelemetry.Context.Properties.Add("InternalIP", requestTelemetry.Context.Location.Ip);                   
            }`

Comment: the IP is always 127.0.0.1 or ::1 -> localhost. also on the remote server.
for the username i managed to get it, but only on failed requests.